# RecyclerView and notifyDataSetChanged LongClick mismatch

Tags: kotlin, checkbox, android-recyclerview, visibility, notifydatasetchanged

I'm having a weird problem with notifyDataSetChanged() in my Recycler Adapter. If I keep 5 items in an array the code works fine and I can check the checkbox at the item I LongClick, but when I add 5 items or more to the array other checkboxes get checked in my list.

I am using a boolean to toggle between VISIBLE and GONE on the checkboxes when the user LongClicks as well.

Here is my code:

```kotlin
class RecyclerAdapter(private val listActivity: ListActivity) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.Holder>() {

    lateinit var binding: ActivityListItemRowBinding
    var checkboxesVisibility = false
    val dummyArrayWorks = arrayOf("000", "111", "222", "333", "444")
    val dummyArrayFails = arrayOf("000", "111", "222", "333", "444", "555")

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): Holder {
        binding = ActivityListItemRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return Holder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = dummyArrayFails.size

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {

        val item = dummyArrayFails[position]
        
        holder.binding.checkbox.visibility = if (checkboxesVisibility) VISIBLE else GONE
        holder.bindItem(item)

        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
            if (!checkboxesVisibility) {
                checkboxesVisibility = true
                holder.binding.checkbox.isChecked = true
                notifyDataSetChanged()
                true
            } else {
                false
            }
        }
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            if (!checkboxesVisibility) {
                //Some other unrelated code
            } else {
                holder.binding.checkbox.isChecked = !holder.binding.checkbox.isChecked
                notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }

    class Holder(internal val binding: ActivityListItemRowBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        var item = String()

        fun bindItem(item: String) {
            this.item = item
            binding.itemPlaceHolder.text = item
        }
    }
}
```

I should add that when I remove the toggle for the checkboxes, and just show the checkboxes on first load, the clicks match the checkmarks without a problem.

Does anybody have any idea of what is going on? All help will be much appreciated!

Comment: If you need more code I'll be happy to add some!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're holding your checked state in the `ViewHolder` itself - you're toggling its checkbox on and off depending on clicks, right?

The way a `RecyclerView` works is that instead of having a `ViewHolder` for every single item (like a `ListView` does), it only creates a handful of them - enough for what's on screen and a few more for scrolling - and *recycles* those, using them to display different items.

That's what `onBindViewHolder` is about - when it needs to display the item at `position`, it hands you a `ViewHolder` from its pool and says here you go, use that to display this item's details. This is where you do things like setting text, changing images, and setting things like checkbox state to reflect that particular item.

---

What you're doing is you're not storing the item's state anywhere, you're just setting the checkbox on the *view holder*. So if you check it, every item that happens to be displayed in that reusable holder object will have its box ticked. That's why you're seeing it pop up on other items - that checked state has nothing to do with the items themselves, just which view holder they all happen to use because of their position in the list.

So instead, you need to keep their checked state somewhere - it could be as simple as a boolean array that matches the length of your item list. Then you just set and get from that when binding your data (displaying it). Working with what you've got:

```
// all default to false
val itemChecked = BooleanArray(items.size)

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: Holder, position: Int) {
    ...
    // when displaying the data, refer to the checked state we're holding
    holder.binding.checkbox.checked = itemChecked[position]
    ...
    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
        ...
        // when checking the box, update our checked state
        // since we're calling notifyDataSetChanged, the item will be redisplayed
        // and onBindViewHolder will be called again (which sets the checkbox)
        itemChecked[position] = true
        // notifyItemChanged(position) is better here btw, just refreshes this one
        notifyDataSetChanged()
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Although I disagree with you on the notifyItemChanged(position) idea. In that case I would probably prefer notifyItemRangeChanged(0, items.size) instead, but I suppose it's a matter of taste ;-)

Comment: I was hoovering around this but I was also (outside of my post) adding an INTEGER property to my SQLite database to keep check of the checked items. This is much cleaner.

Comment: ``notifyItemRangeChanged(0, items.size)`` is better than ``notifyDataSetChanged``, but it's still telling the adapter that every item needs to be updated. ``notifyItemChanged(position)`` is literally just "hey this item has changed so update it" which is what's happening, it's more efficient but it's also more descriptive of what you're doing. Long press item -> update state for this item -> trigger UI refresh of this item to reflect new state

Comment: You'll probably also need that SQL column if you want to persist this state between app runs, but yeah you'll need to store and update that state separately - reading and writing a DB is too slow for UI changes, so you need that in-memory version too. Also if you want to be more efficient, you probably want to set your click listeners on each view holder *once* (you usually do it in the view holder's ``init`` block) and give it a ``position`` property. Then you set its ``position`` in ``onBindViewHolder`` (the position it's currently displaying) and the click listeners just refer to that